# How can I make a table with multiple rotated rows and columns?

Tags: multicolumn, multirow, rotating

I want to make my table look ike this, but also align the lines of the cells wit rotated text

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! What you try so far? Please, be so kind and post a minimal, yet complete, example code illustrating your problem?   Content you can rotate by employing `rotate` and `makecell` packages, or by `rotatebox` defined in the `graphicx` package.

Comment: And. What mean exactly "also align the line of the cells with rotated text"? That cell are aligned with the horizontal center and they are aligned with the bottom of the cell. So?

Comment: Any news? You receive two answer .. does any of them solve your problem satisfactorily. If, please accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of selected answer).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a table like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{%
    labelsep=colon,
    justification=raggedright,
    labelfont=default,
    singlelinecheck=off
}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[]
        \centering
        \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \caption{Table description}
        \label{Some Table}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|cc|ccc|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Complete name}                                                                                                  \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{11}{|c|}{Description}                                                                                                    \\ \hline
            \multirow{4}{*}{Exam} &
            \multirow{4}{*}{Assistance} &
            \multirow{4}{*}{Questionary} &
            \multirow{4}{*}{Homework} &
            \multirow{4}{*}{Second Program} &
            \multirow{4}{*}{Frist Program} &
            \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Grup Characters} &
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{Comments} &
            &
            \\ \cline{9-10}
            &    &    &    &    &    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Date:}                          & \multicolumn{1}{l}{S}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \\ \cline{9-9}
            &    &    &    &    &    & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Serial No:}                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{U} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \\
            &    &    &    &    &    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{No:} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Name} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \\ \hline
            10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}  & Jane Doe                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \\ \hline
            9  & 9  & 9  & 9  & 9  & 9  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{2}  & Jane Doe                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \\ \hline
            8  & 8  & 8  & 8  & 8  & 8  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3}  & Jane Doe                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \\ \hline
            10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{4}  & Jane Doe                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \\ \hline
            5  & 5  & 5  & 5  & 5  & 5  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5}  & Jane Doe                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \\ \hline
            10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6}  & Jane Doe                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- you not provide any code of your table nor information about document layout, so answers can be based only on guessing
- as starting I use @Roland [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573815/how-can-i-make-a-table-with-multiple-rotated-rows-and-columns/573934#573934) (+1)
- in comparison to @Roland answer in the following MWE the following changes are done:

  - for table is used is `tabularx`
  - added rotated column headers as shown in image

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}%
    {\multicolumn{#1}{|c|}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{1}m}%
    {\multicolumn{#1}{l|}{#2}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelsep=colon,
            justification=raggedright,
            labelfont=default,
            singlelinecheck=off
            ]{caption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
\caption{Table description}
\label{Some Table}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Questionary}
    \renewcommand\cellrotangle{60}
    \setcellgapes{1pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{6}{C|}c|c|*{3}{C|}}
    \hline
\mcc[11]{\thead{Complete name}}             \\
    \hline
\mcc[11]{\thead{Description}}               \\
    \hline
\multirow{4}{*}[1.5ex]{\rothead{Exam}}
    &   \multirow{4}{*}[1.5ex]{\rothead{Assistance}}
        &   \multirow{4}{*}[1.5ex]{\rothead{Questionary}}
            &   \multirow{4}{*}[1.5ex]{\rothead{Homework}}
                &   \multirow{4}{*}[1.5ex]{\rothead{Second\\ Program}}
                    &   \multirow{4}{*}[1.5ex]{\rothead{First\\ Program}}
                        &   \mcl[2]{Grup Characters}
                                &   \mcl[3]{Comments}       \\
    \cline{9-10}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   \mcl[2]{Date}
                                &   \mcl[2]{S}
                                    &                       \\
    \cline{9-9}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   \mcl[2]{Serial No:}
                                & \mcl{U} 
                                    &   &                   \\
    \cline{7-8}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   No:
                            &   Name
                                &   &   &                   \\
    \hline
10  & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 1 & Jane Doe &   &   &       \\
    \hline
9   & 9  & 9  & 9  & 9  & 9  & 2 & Jane Doe &   &   &       \\  \hline
8   & 8  & 8  & 8  & 8  & 8  & 3 & Jane Doe &   &   &       \\  \hline
10  & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 4 & Jane Doe &   &   &       \\  \hline
5   & 5  & 5  & 5  & 5  & 5  & 5 & Jane Doe &   &   &       \\  \hline
10  & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 6 & Jane Doe &   &   &       \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]